# Grabbing an attribute's attribute in FetchXML using filters

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

This is my FetchXML...

```
<fetch version="1.0" mapping="logical">
    <entity name="cs_testparameter" >
        <attribute name="cs_testcalculation" />
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

which returns the following:

```
<resultset morerecords="0">
  <result>
    <cs_testcalculation name="Addition" formattedvalue="717640000">717640000</cs_testcalculation>
  </result>
  <result>
    <cs_testcalculation name="Subtraction" formattedvalue="717640001">717640001</cs_testcalculation>
  </result>
  <result>
    <cs_testcalculation name="Multiplication" formattedvalue="717640002">717640002</cs_testcalculation>
  </result>
  <result>
    <cs_testcalculation name="Division" formattedvalue="717640003">717640003</cs_testcalculation>
  </result>
</resultset>
```

I'd like to filter my results so it only returns `TestParameter` entities whose `testCalculation` attribute's name is equal to `Addition` for example. How would I do this?

I know I could filter using the numeric value using...

```
<fetch version="1.0" mapping="logical">
    <entity name="cs_testparameter" >
        <attribute name="cs_testcalculation" />
        <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="cs_testcalculation" operator="eq" value="717640000" />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

...but I'd rather not use the numeric value but rather filter on the name itself. Is this possible?

---

**Edit**: In the end, I will be using this to do something like...

```
string fetchQuery = @"--my fetchXML here...--";
FetchExpression fetchTestParameters = new FetchExpression(fetchQuery);
EntityCollection testParameters = context.RetrieveMultiple(fetchTestParameters);

foreach (var testParameter in testParameters.Entities)
{
    switch (testParameter.cs_testcalculation["name"])
    {
      case "Addition":
        //do something...
      case "Subtraction":
        //do something else...
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you executing your fetxml? using the retrievemultiple will always give you the results collection where retrieve will return the entity xml entity you really want.

Comment: I don't know of any way to fetch the results using optionset name values, however if you explain your objective behind why you want to fetch results using optionset name value? Anybody may suggest a workaround for this.

Comment: @Shane_Yo I am using RetrieveMultiple

Comment: @AliLee I've updated my question and added what my objective in the end is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aswering your recent edit:

You are just using enums to make the code more readable and scalable, but in essence you are comparing numbers. The correct answer will be "**It is not possible**" but your approach to handle this is **correct**.

Other way to make this is using FormattedValues wich let you to ask for the name instead of the value.

*Late bound code:*

```
entity.FormattedValues["cs_TestCalculation"]
```

or

```
entity.GetFormattedAttributeValue["cs_TestCalculation"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround for what I'm doing:

- my FetchXML is still the same
- I've generated the enums of the option sets using crmsvcutil and added it to my project
- my `foreach` now looks like:

---

```
foreach (var testParameter in testParameters.Entities)
{
    switch (((cs_testparameter) testParameter).cs_TestCalculation.Value)
    {
      case (int)cs_testcalculation.Addition:
        //do something...
      case (int)cs_testcalculation.Subtraction:
        //do something else...
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great. But I am just wondering why did't you use option set integer values (hard coded) in the swtich ... case statement simply, instead of this long workaround?

Comment: @AliLee The integer values don't make sense to whoever is taking over the code. The values might also change entirely. If there is a change, it would be better to update the early bound type and option set classes, rather than the main code.

Comment: I remember (needs to be confirmed) if we change the integer values of an option set, the existing values in entity records become invalid. In other words, it wouldn't be a cascading change. On the other hand, name values are more likely to be changed due to spell errors, or name enhancement etc.

Personally, i feel using the name values in the code for performing tasks is not a good approach.